# splitview master keyboard crash

Tags: ios, swift

I have been developing a Splitview app for several months now. I'm attempting to add search functionality.

I started with a searchbar and searchController on my tableview/navigation item. Both gave me the same result. The instant you tap the text view, the blackboardd crashes and the the iPad restarts (White Apple, black screen). At first I figured it was an issue with the searchbar class. So I tried adding plain old textView/textField. All gave the same result. As far as I can tell, it is the keyboard. I am using the keyboard in several other view controllers, this issue is only under my masterViewController in my splitview (only a subclass). If the keyboard is initiated anywhere under that view, my app crashes. I've searched the internet high and low. I've created a fresh splitview project, and do not get this error. I am running Xcode 7.0.1 with iOS 9.0.2. Same result in Simulator and real device. I'm at my whit's end and really need search functionality. 
If there's any more information I could provide, please let me know.

In xCode, all I see is the following:

```
2015-10-18 15:17:32.343 Test Store App[2359:501341] <CATransformLayer: 0x15c669480> - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect
2015-10-18 15:17:32.345 Test Store App[2359:501341] <CATransformLayer: 0x15c78e170> - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect
2015-10-18 15:17:32.347 Test Store App[2359:501341] <CATransformLayer: 0x15c78e270> - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect
2015-10-18 15:17:32.736 Test Store App[2359:501351] Terminating since there is no system app.
```

In the device logs I see the following

```
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad backboardd[2192] <Error>: -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a1911ea8
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad backboardd[2192] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a1911ea8'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x185cd8f5c 0x19a787f80 0x185cdfc6c 0x185cdcc14 0x185be0dcc 0x185cc0a64 0x185cc0b94 0x18d0ad3f0 0x185bd70b0 0x185bdf830 0x185c0c80c 0x100089990 0x19af757b0 0x19af75770 0x19af8175c 0x19af79274 0x19af8362c 0x19af8334c 0x19b189478 0x19b189028)
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad SpringBoard[2194] <Warning>: Terminating since backboardd has gone away.
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.backboardd[2192]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Abort trap: 6
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad imagent[61] <Notice>: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=3
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad imagent[61] <Warning>: [Warning] Unable to get entitlements for client task. Error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process"
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad imagent[61] <Warning>: [Warning] Denying xpc connection, task does not have entitlement: com.apple.private.icfcallserver  ((null):2194)
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad imagent[61] <Warning>: [Warning] Denying xpc connection, task does not have entitlement: com.apple.private.icfcallserver  ((null):2194)
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad mediaserverd[1952] <Notice>: '' (pid = 2194) setting DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad Test Store App[2210] <Warning>: XPC connection interrupted
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad Test Store App[2210] <Warning>: Terminating since there is no system app.
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad com.apple.accessibility.AccessibilityUIServer[2195] <Warning>: XPC connection interrupted
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad com.apple.accessibility.AccessibilityUIServer[2195] <Warning>: Terminating since there is no system app.
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad MobileMail[2202] <Warning>: XPC connection interrupted
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad MobileMail[2202] <Warning>: Terminating since there is no system app.
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad diagnosticd[1477] <Error>: error evaluating process info - pid: 2192, puniqueid: 2192
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad backboardd[2217] <Notice>: made new hangtracer connection:0x13ee06570 
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad backboardd[2217] <Warning>: PUIProgressWindow initWithOptions: 4 contextLevel: 2999 appearance: 0
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad backboardd[2217] <Warning>: main display width 1536 height 2048 framebuffer width 1536 height 2048 scale 2 orientation 0
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad backboardd[2217] <Warning>: PUIProgressWindow not using PreBoard appearance
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad backboardd[2217] <Warning>: _sideways 0
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad backboardd[2217] <Warning>: _renderWithIOSurface 0
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad backboardd[2217] <Warning>: layer position 768 1024 bounds 0 0 1536 2048
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad backboardd[2217] <Warning>: PUIProgressWindow trying to load image source for /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProgressUI.framework/apple-logo@2x~ipad.png
Oct 18 14:53:34 Brandons-iPad aggregated[2203] <Warning>: Connection interrupted!
```

Comment: It sounds like you've found an iOS bug which is causing backboardd, the window server process on iOS, to crash.  You should file a bug with Apple and attach the crash log for backboardd.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll let Apple know.